# How could I place text inside a document at the script tag?

Tags: javascript, tags

I'm wondering if its possible to write in a document with Javascript by using the script tags as a reference, instead of some section found with `document.getElementById("id")` or something like that.

Example: I have a form where, when you put values in the inputs and press enter, it writes text to the document that uses the previously entered values.

Now, I know it would obviously be easier to go ahead and send it to a function with onSubmit in the head, but with the way this is set up it formats easier if I can write it out in this way. So, if anyone know how this could be achieved, tell me please, thanks.

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 15pt; padding-top: 70px;">
    <form onSubmit="reveal(this.a.value, this.b.value)">
        a = <input name="a"/>
        b = <input name="b"/>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <script>
        function reveal(a, b)
        {
            [math]a + b = c[math]
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

You can see what I have so far here on it. If anyone can tell me how to write the `[math]a + b = c[math]` to the document using the script tags as reference.

**Clarification Of Attempted Result:** `[math]a + b = c[math]` represents the text that I want to place in the document, as of now I don't have anything set up to actually write it, which is why its just sitting there. I want it to be placed in the document at the location of the script tags, the ones surrounding the function reveal(). How can I place that text in the document at the location of the surrounding script tags?

Comment: What do you mean by "script tags as reference"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is `[math]a + b = c[math]`?

Comment: I have in the code a function inside script tags. I want to effectively just place the text right there, where the function is, instead of finding a div element with an id and replacing its innerHTML, or something like that

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by manually writing text into `script` tags? I'm not sure what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to do: find the `script` tag that has the function `reveal()`, then insert the string before or after the `script` tag.

If it is the case, then try this: (jQuery is used for the sake of simplicity)

```
var tag = $("script").filter(function () {
    return /reveal\(\)/.test(this.innerText);     //Find the script tag that has
});                                               // the function "reveal()"

tag.after("[math]a + b = c[math]");               //Insert your text

    - or -

$("<span>[math]a + b = c[math]</span>").replaceAll(tag);  //Replace it
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cDbGz/)</kbd>

---

PS:

If you already have a `script` tag, then why don't you just do this:

```
<script>
    function reveal(){
        blah();
    }
    document.write("[math]a + b = c[math]");    //The text will be inserted where
                                                //the script tag is located at
</script>
```

Comment: That is what I want to happen, the second one, I want it inserted at the script tag. But how do I get it to show there only when the function is called? If I place it inside the function, then it just goes and replaces the entire document.

Comment: @DavidGrabon - It won't replace the entire document: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cDbGz/1/ It will write the text after the `script` tag.

Comment: It doesn't replace it if the document.write("") is sitting outside the function, but then it prints the text without waiting for the function to be called, which isn't what I'm aiming for, I want it to print when the function is called

Comment: @DavidGrabon - If you look closely at my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cDbGz/1/), `document.write` is inside a function.

Comment: Its inside the script tags but not the function reveal(), which is what is supposed to call it

Comment: @DavidGrabon - I kind of understand what you are talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cDbGz/2/